# I have a CSS and I want it to be aligned in-line

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I have a CSS file and I want all the items to be aligned in-line like this:

[image]

What I have done so far is:

[image]

Its not working as I'm using Material UI. This is my CSS and ReactJS code:

```
<FormControl component="fieldset">
                <RadioGroup column
                    aria-label="survey"
                    name="survey"
                >
                    <FormControlLabel
                        value="dont_schedule"
                        control={<Radio />}
                        label={<div>Do not schedule</div>}
                        labelPlacement="Comedy"
                    />

                    <FormControlLabel
                        value="sync_once_day"
                        control={<Radio />}
                        label={<div>Sync once in a day on
                            <FormControl className="form__section">
                                <InputLabel>Age</InputLabel>
                                <Select
                                    labelId="demo-customized-select-label"
                                    id="demo-customized-select"
                                >
                                    <MenuItem value="Monday">Monday</MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem value="Tuesday">Tuesday</MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem value="Webnesday">Webnesday</MenuItem>
                                </Select>
                            </FormControl>
                        </div>}
                        labelPlacement="Crime"
                    />
                </RadioGroup>
            </FormControl>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.form__section{
    padding: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use flexbox.

```js
.form_section{
display: flex;
align-items:center;
}
```